# How to make this code work without repeating the numbers?

Tags: c#, random, arraylist

I need to print numbers from 1 to 50 in random order without repeating 
it .

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     ArrayList r = new ArrayList();

     Random ran = new Random();      
     for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
     {
        r.Add(ran.Next(1,51));

     }

     for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(r[i]);
     Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12294128/generating-random-numbers-and-inserting-into-array-without-repeats

Comment: Don't use `ArrayList` anymore. It belongs old days when C# doesn't have _generics_. Use `List<T>` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is this check if the number already exists in the list and if so get another one:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ArrayList r = new ArrayList();

    Random ran = new Random();      
    int num = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        do { num = ran.Next(1, 51); } while (r.Contains(num));
        r.Add(num);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
       Console.WriteLine(r[i]);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Edit: This will greatly increase the effeciency, preventing long pauses waiting for a non-collision number:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> numbers = new List<int>();

        Random ran = new Random();
        int number = 0;
        int min = 1;
        int max = 51;

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            do
            {
                number = ran.Next(min, max);
            }
            while (numbers.Contains(number));

            numbers.Add(number);

            if (number == min) min++;
            if (number == max - 1) max--;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want here is the [Fisher Yates Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)

Here is the algorithm as implemented by [Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/the-danger-of-naivete.html)

```
cards = Enumerable.Range(1, 50).ToList();
for (int i = cards.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
  int n = ran.Next(i + 1);
  int temp = cards[i];
  cards[i] = cards[n];
  cards[n] = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to repeat the numbers between 1 and 50, your best bet is to populate a list with the numbers 1 to 50 and then shuffle the contents.  There's a good post on shuffling here:
[Randomize a List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt-in-c-sharp)